# Magento logged in on random customer

Tags: cache, customer-account, logging

When using my Magento webshop I noticed that sometimes I am logged in on a customers account. How can this be happening?

Comment: Are you using Varnish, anything similar or a full page cache?

Comment: We have a full page cache plugin from our hosting company, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a full page cache plugin, so I think this where you should search the error.

While many of the parts of a magento site can be cached, some depend on the current session: the cart, for example, or whose user's data is shown in the "my account" area. Because if this, fpc-extensions must implement some kind of hole-punching. If this functionality has an error, it is possible that a personalized version a page is cached, and every user is able to see the session days of another specific user.